# Optimize long running insert query

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have the following code that it works fine. My problem is the insert took more than three hours.

How can I optimize the insert query in sql table?

```
foreach(var sheetName in GetExcelSheetNames(connectionString)) {
    using(OleDbConnection con1 = new OleDbConnection(connectionString)) {

        var dt = new DataTable();
        string query = string.Format("SELECT  * FROM [{0}]", sheetName);
        con1.Open();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(query, con1);
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString)) {
            con.Open();
            for (int i = 2; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
                for (int j = 1; j < dt.Columns.Count; j += 3) {
                    try {
                        var s = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
                        var dt1 = DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("fr-FR"));
                        var s1 = dt.Rows[i][j].ToString();

                        var s2 = dt.Rows[i][j + 1].ToString();
                        var s3 = sheetName.Remove(sheetName.Length - 1);

                        {
                            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [Obj CA MPX] ([CA TTC],[VAL MRG TTC],[CA HT],[VAL MRG HT],[Rayon],[Date],[Code Site]) VALUES(@ca,@val,@catHT ,@valHT ,@rayon, @date ,@sheetName )", con);
                            command.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.Date).Value = dt1;
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ca", s1);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", s2);
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rayon", dt.Rows[0][j].ToString());
                            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sheetName", s3);
                            command.Parameters.Add("@catHT", DBNull.Value).Value = DBNull.Value;
                            command.Parameters.Add("@valHT", DBNull.Value).Value = DBNull.Value;
                            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Are you sure that bottle neck is inserting rows and not the reading values from Excel(As I assume from you code?

Comment: How many source rows are we talking about? SqlBulkCopy may be a solution but before I post an answer I'd like to get an idea of how many rows are being inserted - if it's not gazillions then it probably won't help.

Comment: @StephenByrne it is about than one million rows .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should save it as file and use bulk insert

https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms188365%28v=sql.120%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has the option of using a [Bulk Insert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188365.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

[Here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/) is a good article on importing a csv.

Answer (score 0):

You should first read this article from Eric Lippert: [Which is faster?](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).
Keep this in mind while trying to optimize your process.

The insert took 3 hours, but have you inserted 10 items or 900.000.000.000 items?
If it's the last one, maybe 3 hours are pretty good.

What is your database? SQL Server 2005 Express? SQL Server 2014 Enterprise? 
The advices could differ.

Without more details, we will only be able to give you suggestions, that could or could not apply depending on your configuration.
Here are some on the top of my head:

- Is the bottleneck on the DB side? Check the execution plan, add indexes if needed
- Beware of `AddWithValue`, it can prevent the use of indexes in your query
- If you are loading a lot of data on a non-live database, you could use a lighter [recovery model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189275.aspx) to prevent having a lot of useless logs (using Bulk load will use automatically `BULKED_LOGGED`, or you could activate the SIMPLE recovery model (`alter database [YourDB] set recovery SIMPLE`, don't forget to re-enable the `FULL` recovery model after)
- Are there other alternatives than loading data from an Excel file? Can't you use another database instead or converting the Excel file to a CSV?
- What does the performance monitor tells you? Maybe you need better hardware (more ram, faster disks, RAID), or move some heavily used files (mdf, ldf) on separate disks.
- You could copy the Excel file several times and use parallelization, load in different tables that will be partitions of your final table.

This list could continue forever.

Here is an interesting article about optimizing data loading: [We Loaded 1TB in 30 Minutes with SSIS, and So Can You](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537533%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)
This article is focused on SSIS but some advices do not apply only to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can put several (e.g. 100) inserts into a string using a string builder. Use an index for the parameter names. Note that you can have a maximum of 2100 parameters for one query.

```
StringBuilder batch = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < pageSize; i++)
{
  batch.AppendFormat(
    @"INSERT INTO [Obj CA MPX] ([CA TTC],[VAL MRG TTC], ...) VALUES(@ca{0},@val{0}, ...)"
    i);
  batch.AppendLine();
  batch.AppendLine();
}

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(batch.ToString(), con)

// append parameters, using the index
for (int i = 0; i < pageSize; i++)
{
  command.Parameters.Add("@date" + i, SqlDbType.Date).Value = dt1[i];
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ca" + i, s1[i]);
  // ...
}

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Of course this is not finished, you have to integrate the pages into your existing loops, which may not be too simple.

Alternatively, you do not use parameters and put the arguments directly into the query. This way, you can create much larger batches (I would put 1000 to 10000 inserts into one batch) and it's much easier to implement.